# Delete from multiple tables is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Scenario: There are 4 tables [A,B,C,D,E]. I wanna delete from all of them in one query. And i'm applying the following query.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db")
$del="DELETE a,b,c,d,e FROM `A` as a INNER JOIN `B` as b INNER JOIN `C` as c  
INNER JOIN
 `D` as d INNER JOIN `E` as e ON a.user_id=b.user_id AND a.user_id=c.user_id     
AND a.user_id=d.user_id AND a.user_id=e.user_id 
WHERE login.user_id= '25'";
$que=mysqli_query($con,$del)
if($del){
echo "Its done";
}
else{
echo mysqli_error($con);}
```

It's deleting fine when there is data in every table against that id. But when there is no data in some table lets say in D and E, the query doesn't work and it doesn't delete anything then. I think its because i have put AND operator between the 'ON'. I don't know much about sql. So, someone please help me. And one more thing its not giving any errors its printing its done. 
Hope it makes sense to you.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need separate query for all the tables if you want to delete specific record from all the tables or use `mysql cascade action` in foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Every join has its own `ON` clause

```
DELETE a,b,c,d,e 
FROM `A` as a 
INNER JOIN `B` as b ON a.user_id=b.user_id
LEFT JOIN `C` as c ON a.user_id=c.user_id  
INNER JOIN `D` as d ON a.user_id=d.user_id
LEFT JOIN `E` as e ON a.user_id=e.user_id    
WHERE a.user_id= '25'
```

Comment: same result... its not deleteing from a beacuse there is no data in C and E or any table.

Comment: Then use a `left join` instead of an `inner join` on the tables that can have no link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$del="DELETE a,b,c,d,e 
    FROM `A` as a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `B` as b ON a.user_id=b.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `C` as c ON a.user_id=c.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `D` as d ON a.user_id=d.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `E` as e ON a.user_id=e.user_id
WHERE login.user_id= '25'";
```

Comment: @mastermind, Are you sure all the tables have same user with id 25? this will not work if the user does not exist in any of tables.

Comment: Thats what im saying...that there is user_id column..but there is no data against 25..actually its up to user to put data or not.. So, im trying to do things the both ways..

Comment: if there is data in all tables then the query deletes correctly..but if there is no data even if in one table.it doesnot work...So is there a way to delete despite of that fact through inner join??

Comment: use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` then. updating answer now